# How to get chrome to recognize bookmarks in file download URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome

I have searched everywhere and cannot find how to get chrome to recognize bookmarks in a doc download. (It's hard to search for this when bookmarks and anchors have two meanings).

For instance a URL http://my.website.com/myfile.doc#mybookmark downloads the file just fine, but I cannot get the browser to scroll to the bookmarks. I've tried the build in google docs viewer, as well as microsofts and neither work.
https://products.office.com/en-US/office-online/view-office-documents-online
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=my.website.com/myfile#mybookmark

Does anyone know how this can be done?

If I can do it inside of the code, or in some other way please feel free to say so. I just need to have the client download a file from link and it go to the bookmark I specify.

(The site is written in VB.net, the clients use Chrome) C# is fine as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I've been searching for a few days and came across a few mehods. I can either write the file into binary and push it to the client (works great for displaying the word document, but still no ability to move the client to the bookmark), or I can read the file and pull all of the text out positioning through Jquery (will not work for client needs). Does anyone have any ideas at least? I'm at a dead end. Thanks.

Comment: So far, we've adding word to the server and are opening it from code, saving the file as pdf with bookmarks, and displaying it. This is VERY ugly, but the only way we could figure out without using 3rd party plugins.